# No Incoming Call Screen Shows & No Sound [Wildfire S Cyanogenmod 10.1]

Tags: htc-wildfire-s

I have updated my HTC wildfire S to cyanogen-mod 10.1 yesterday.

I am facing Two main Issues.

1st: I am unable to receive a call because when i called from other cell, there was no incoming call on WFS but on the other cell after one beep there was a "Number Busy" notification.

2nd: Power button does not enable the pattern lock.As i have set a pattern from setting>security.

Please help me with this.